# Change custom post type permalink to show name of post from another custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have the post types `competitions` and `class`. My URLs look like this:

```
http://example.com/competition/postname/
```

and

```
http://example.com/class/postname/
```

I have meta field in the class post type that shows the post id of the competition in which this class belongs. I need to have my permalink for class like this:

```
http://example.com/competition/competitionpostname/classpostname/
```

Comment: Please share your custom post type code and meta field name.

Comment: [Have a look at the answer I wrote for this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264530/rewrite-rules-for-custom-post-type-attached-to-another-custom-post-type).